# Override Global Authorize in Controller instead of Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a custom authorize, which is *ignored* when an action has `[Authorize]`:

```
public class MyGlobalAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // check if action is decorated with an Authorize...
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
        if (action.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true))
            return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

...then I configured it in the global filters, only allowing admins by default:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyGlobalAuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin" });
    }
}
```

If I decorate an action like this:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [Authorize] // non-admins can access this action..
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```

...it works fine. However, if I put the `[Authorize]` in controller, `MyGlobalAuthorizeAttribute` won't detect it.

I found many examples of overriding, but all of them is about an **action** overriding a **controller** or a **global** authorize, but not a controller overriding a global authorize.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to check the ControllerDescriptor:

```
var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
if (action.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true))
    return;

if (action.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true))
    return;
```

[Documentation for ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerdescriptor.isdefined(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I was looking in `filterContext.Controller` and `filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext`, when it was just in front of my eyes, inside `action`. Thanks a lot!!!